# PHP code doesn't update the MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

```
session_start(); 
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$date= getdate();
$update="UPDATE `mstr_login` SET `last_logindatetime`='$date' WHERE `username`='$username'";
mysql_query($update);
```

I have written this code but nothing was updated in my database table. Another thing is that I'm using wamp server so I tried this code to update table and I found it changed​ but the value became 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Comment: What does your http servers error log file reveal as issue?

Comment: Why not you set default value of `last_login` (whatever your column name) column `current_timestamp`

Comment: Apart from that a general hint: seems you are following some tutorial which is very outdated: you are using the old `mysql_...()` functions, those are outdated and long deprecated, they have even been removed in current php versions. So do yourself a favor and read and learn about the current `mysqli` extension to work with a MySQL database. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Or pdo extension

Comment: Query seems to be correct, checked if a valid connection is initiated.

Comment: have you checked the output of getdate() . mysql timestamp column requires a certain format usually 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$update="UPDATE `mstr_login` SET `last_logindatetime`=now() 
         WHERE `username`='$username'";
```

but, where is your connection?

So more, you should use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: @Fred -ii-    Here is my connection <?php     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" ,"") or die ("Error");    mysqli_select_db($conn,"crs") or die ("Error in selecting database");    ?>    Every thing is working perfect but last login change action is not performed well.

Comment: In the edit with revised code, please note that you can easily store the Date Time value in VARCHAR and retrieve it. Formatting is also within your control everytime you retrieve the value.